# Unable to run PCA on a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pca

I am trying to run PCA on the loan dataset - find [test](https://github.com/shri1407/Loan-Prediction-Dataset/blob/master/test.csv) here and [train](https://github.com/shri1407/Loan-Prediction-Dataset/blob/master/train.csv).

The code snippet is as follows,

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = pca.transform(X_test)
explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

However, on running the same, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-829bdba63de3> in <module>
      3 pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
      4 X_train = pca.fit_transform(X_train)
----> 5 X_test = pca.transform(X_test)
      6 explained_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\base.py in transform(self, X)
    127         X = check_array(X)
    128         if self.mean_ is not None:
--> 129             X = X - self.mean_
    130         X_transformed = np.dot(X, self.components_.T)
    131         if self.whiten:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (185,112) (2,)
```

Can someone help me on this?
I don't where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is `X_test.shape`?

Comment: ```(185,112)```

Comment: What is X_train.shape?

Comment: ```(429, 2 )```

Comment: Your X_test.shape *must* have the same second dimension as X_train.  That is where the error is from.  Why is your X_test the wrong shape?  Who knows.... you'd need to show us how X_train and X_test get assigned.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Solved the problem.

Comment: @Scott, Please write this as your answer and I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a PCA only require :

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
```

Maybe you should drop labels on train, join test and train then do PCA.